# Adjust the width of longtable

Tags: longtable, width

I have to adjust the width in one of my tables. I have looked at other questions regarding this - but I cannot seem to figure it out.

My preamble:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,autocite=inline]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}
\usepackage[labelfont={bf, it}]{caption}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize, textfont=it}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 9in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{\fontsize{10}{12}}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\sloppy
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} %[hidelinks] fjerner det røde i table of contents
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{longtable}
```

My table:

```
\begin{longtable}[H]{l|l|l|l|l}
\label{MTPSLLONG}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F2F1E1}\textbf{Species}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F2F1E1}\textbf{MTPSL}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F2F1E1}\textbf{Substrate(s)}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F2F1E1}\textbf{Product(s)}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F2F1E1}\textbf{Reference}} \\ \hline
\endfirsthead

\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F2F1E1}\textbf{Species}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F2F1E1}\textbf{MTPSL}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F2F1E1}\textbf{Substrate(s)}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F2F1E1}\textbf{Product(s)}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F2F1E1}\textbf{Reference}} \\ \hline
\endfoot

 & SmMTPSL1 & (E,E)-FPP & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}(E)- nerolidol, α-copaene, \\ β-elemene, γ-cadinene, δ-cadinene, \\ unidentified oxygenated sesquiterpene\end{tabular} &  \\ \cline{2-4}
 & SmMTPSL13 & None & None &  \\ \cline{2-4}
 & SmMTPSL17 & (E,E)-FPP & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}α-copaene, β-elemene, \\ γ-cadinene, δ-cadinene, \\ unidentified oxygenated sesquiterpene, \\ germacrene, bicyclogermacrene, \\ α-cadinene\end{tabular} &  \\ \cline{2-4}
 & SmMTPSL22 & (E,E)-FPP, GPP & (E)- nerolidol, limonene, linalool &  \\ \cline{2-4}
 & SmMTPSL26 & (E,E)-FPP & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}unidentified sesquiterpene A, \\ unidentified sesquiterpene B, \\ 2-epi-(E)-β-caryophyllene\end{tabular} &  \\ \cline{2-4}
\multirow{-6}{*}{\textit{Selaginella moellendorffii}} & SmMTPSL30 & None & None & \multirow{-6}{*}{Li et. al (2012)} \\ \hline
 & MpMTPSL1 & None & None &  \\ \cline{2-4}
 & MpMTPSL2 & NPP & Not defined &  \\ \cline{2-4}
 & MpMTPSL3 & (E,E)-FPP & Not defined &  \\ \cline{2-4}
 & MpMTPSL4 & (E,E)-FPP & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}(2)-a-Gurjunene (3), \\  5-Hydroxy-a-Gurjunene, and others\\ not defined\end{tabular} &  \\ \cline{2-4}
 & MpMTPSL5 & (E,E)-FPP & Not defined &  \\ \cline{2-4}
 & MpMTPSL6 & NPP & Not defined &  \\ \cline{2-4}
 & MpMTPSL7 & (E,E)-FPP & Not defined &  \\ \cline{2-4}
 & MpMTPSL8 & None & None &  \\ \cline{2-4}
\multirow{-9}{*}{\textit{Marchantia polymorpha}} & MpMTPSL9 & (E,E)-FPP & Not defined & \multirow{-9}{*}{Kumar et. al (2016)} \\ \hline
 & Liv-IRBN-MTPSL2 & GPP, (E,E)-FPP, (Z,E)-FPP & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Myrcene, limonene, (Z)-β-ocimene, \\ (E)-β-ocimene, linalool, \\ bicycloelemene, bicyclogermacrene, \\ unidentified sesquiterpene hydrocarbons\end{tabular} &  \\ \cline{2-4}
\multirow{-2}{*}{\textit{Scapania nemorea}} & Liv-IRBN-MTPSL4 & (E,E)-FPP, (Z,E)-FPP, (Z,Z)-FPP, (E,E,E)-GGPP & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}α-isocomene, β-elemene, \\ (E)-β-caryophyllene, (E)-β-farnesene, \\ nerolidol, dactylol, (E)-β-farnesene, \\ (Z)-α-bisabolene, γ-curcumene, \\ zingiberene, multiple unidentified ST, \\ β-sesquiphellandrene, \\ unidentified sesquiterpene hydrocarbons, \\ unidentified diterpenes\end{tabular} &  \\ \cline{1-4}
\textit{Sphagnum lescurii} & Mos-GOWD-MTPSL2 & GPP & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Myrcene, (Z)-β-ocimene, \\ (E)-β-ocimene, linalool, allo-ocimene\end{tabular} &  \\ \cline{1-4}
\textit{Pseudotaxiphyllum elegans} & Mos-QKQO-MTPSL3 & (E,E)-FPP, (Z,E)-FPP, (Z,Z)-FPP & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}γ-curcumen, α-zingiberene, \\ β-bisabolene, β-curcumene, \\ sesquiphellandrene, (E)-α-bisabolene, \\ (Z)-α-bisabolene, γ-curcumene, \\ zingiberene, β-sesquiphellandrene\end{tabular} &  \\ \cline{1-4}
\textit{Anomodon rostratus} & Mos-VBMM-MTPSL3 & (E,E)-FPP, (Z,E)-FPP, (Z,Z)-FPP, (E,E,E)-GGPP & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}(E)-β-farnesene, γ-curcumene, \\ α-zingiberen, β-bisabolene, \\ β-curcumene, (E)-α-bisabolene,  \\ (Z)-γ- bisabolene, (E)-γ-bisabolene, \\ β-bisabolol, α-bisabolol, β-bisabolene, \\ (Z)-γ-bisabolene, (Z)-α-bisabolene, \\ γ-curcumene, (E)-γ- bisabolene,\\ multiple unidentified diterpenes\end{tabular} &  \\ \cline{1-4}
\textit{Anthoceros punctatus} & Hon-ApMTPSL7 & GPP, (E,E)-FPP, (Z,E)-FPP, (Z,Z)-FPP &  &  \\ \cline{1-4}
\textit{Myriopteris eatonii} & Mon-GSXD-MTPSL3 & (E,E)-FPP, (Z,E)-FPP & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}(Z,E)-α-farnesene, (E,E)-α-farnesene, \\ (E)-β-farnesene, (E,E)-α-farnesene\end{tabular} &  \\ \cline{1-4}
\textit{Pityrogramma trifoliata} & Mon-UJTT-MTPSL4 & GPP, (E,E)-FPP, (Z,E)-FPP, (Z,Z)-FPP & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Myrcene, (Z)-β-ocimene, \\ (E)-β-ocimene, linalool, \\ protoillud-6-ene, \\ multiple unidentified ST, \\ epi-bicyclosesquiphellandrene, \\ γ-cadinene, δ-cadinene, α-cadinene, \\ γ-curcumene\end{tabular} &  \\ \cline{1-4}
\textit{Woodsia scopulina} & Mon-YJJY-MTPSL1 & (E,E)-FPP, (Z,E)-FPP, (Z,Z)-FPP & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Protoillud-6-ene, \\ multiple unidentified ST, \\ epi-bicyclosesquiphellandrene, \\ γ-cadinene, δ-cadinene, α-cadinene, \\ γ-curcumene\end{tabular} & \multirow{-9}{*}{Jia et. al (2016)} \\ \hline
\textit{Porphyridium purpureum} & PpMTPSL & (E,E)-FPP, (E,E,E)-GGPP & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}β-Elemene, aristol-9-ene, β-copaene, \\ germacrene A, \\ multiple unidentified ST, \\ unidentified oxygenated sesquiterpene\end{tabular} &  \\ \cline{1-4}
 & EaMTPSL1 & GPP, (E,E)-FPP & Linalol, nerolidol &  \\ \cline{2-4}
\multirow{-2}{*}{\textit{Erythrolobus australicus}} & EaMTPSL2 & (E,E)-FPP & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}β-Elemene, aristol-9-ene, β-copaene, \\ unidentified oxygenated sesquiterpene, \\ α-ylangene, α-muurolene, \\ multiple unidentified ST, \\ (Z)-α-bisabolene epoxide\end{tabular} & \multirow{-3}{*}{Wei 2019} \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
```

A picture of some of it:
[image]

Comment: Please make you code compilable. Which documentclass do you use? Please alo make your example code more minimal. There are a lot of packages that are not related to the longtable.

Comment: Your longtable misses its caption as well as a `\\ ` after the label.

Comment: `longtable` environments do not float. Hence, the `[H]` placement specifier has no effect at all (except to add to the code clutter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make your table fit into the textwidth, I would suggest the following redesign. In the following MWE, I have commented out all the packages that are not directly related to the table, I have added `booktabs` for horizontal lines, `makecell` for the column headers and `xltabular` instead of `longtable` for the `X` type column. To efficiently make use f the `X` type columns, I have also removed all nested tabulars and the associated `\\`s. In addition, I have removed most horizontal and all vertical lines. To save space and reduce the amount of wasted white space in the first and last column and potential problems uf `\multirow`and mid-table page breaks, I have removed them alltogether and added section-like headers to the table in which I combined the "Species"  and "Reference"  information. Since you use `biblatex`, I suggest you replace the manually entered citation information (Such as "Li et. al (2012)") by the appropriate `biblatex` commands.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,autocite=inline]{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}
\usepackage[labelfont={bf, it}]{caption}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize, textfont=it}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
%\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
%\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{multicol}
%\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{tabu}
%\usepackage{rotating}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 9in}]{geometry}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\pagestyle{fancy}
%\fancyhead[L]{\fontsize{10}{12}}
\linespread{1.5}
%\usepackage{times}
%\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
%\sloppy

%\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} %[hidelinks] fjerner det røde i table of contents
\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{ll>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\caption{caption text here}\label{MTPSLLONG}\\
\toprule
 \thead{MTPSL} & \thead{Substrate(s)} & \thead{Product(s)}  \\ 
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption*{caption text here - continued}\\
\toprule
 \thead{MTPSL} & \thead{Substrate(s)} & \thead{Product(s)}  \\ 
\midrule
\endhead
\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\emph{Selaginella moellendorffii} Li et. al (2012)}\\
  SmMTPSL1 & (E,E)-FPP & (E)- nerolidol, α-copaene,  β-elemene, γ-cadinene, δ-cadinene,  unidentified oxygenated sesquiterpene   \\ 
  SmMTPSL13 & None & None   \\ 
  SmMTPSL17 & (E,E)-FPP & α-copaene, β-elemene,  γ-cadinene, δ-cadinene,  unidentified oxygenated sesquiterpene,  germacrene, bicyclogermacrene,  α-cadinene   \\ 
  SmMTPSL22 & (E,E)-FPP, GPP & (E)- nerolidol, limonene, linalool   \\ 
  SmMTPSL26 & (E,E)-FPP & unidentified sesquiterpene A,  unidentified sesquiterpene B,  2-epi-(E)-β-caryophyllene  \\ 
 SmMTPSL30 & None & None  \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\emph{Marchantia polymorpha} Kumar et. al (2016)}\\
  MpMTPSL1 & None & None   \\ 
  MpMTPSL2 & NPP & Not defined   \\ 
  MpMTPSL3 & (E,E)-FPP & Not defined   \\
  MpMTPSL4 & (E,E)-FPP & (2)-a-Gurjunene (3), 5-Hydroxy-a-Gurjunene, and others not define   \\ 
  MpMTPSL5 & (E,E)-FPP & Not defined   \\ 
  MpMTPSL6 & NPP & Not defined   \\ 
  MpMTPSL7 & (E,E)-FPP & Not defined   \\
  MpMTPSL8 & None & None   \\ 
\midrule
% & Liv-IRBN-MTPSL2 & GPP, (E,E)-FPP, (Z,E)-FPP & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Myrcene, limonene, (Z)-β-ocimene, \\ (E)-β-ocimene, linalool, \\ bicycloelemene, bicyclogermacrene, \\ unidentified sesquiterpene hydrocarbons\end{tabular} &  \\ \cline{2-4}
%\multirow{-2}{*}{\textit{Scapania nemorea}} & Liv-IRBN-MTPSL4 & (E,E)-FPP, (Z,E)-FPP, (Z,Z)-FPP, (E,E,E)-GGPP & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}α-isocomene, β-elemene, \\ (E)-β-caryophyllene, (E)-β-farnesene, \\ nerolidol, dactylol, (E)-β-farnesene, \\ (Z)-α-bisabolene, γ-curcumene, \\ zingiberene, multiple unidentified ST, \\ β-sesquiphellandrene, \\ unidentified sesquiterpene hydrocarbons, \\ unidentified diterpenes\end{tabular} &  \\ \cline{1-4}
%\textit{Sphagnum lescurii} & Mos-GOWD-MTPSL2 & GPP & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Myrcene, (Z)-β-ocimene, \\ (E)-β-ocimene, linalool, allo-ocimene\end{tabular} &  \\ \cline{1-4}
%\textit{Pseudotaxiphyllum elegans} & Mos-QKQO-MTPSL3 & (E,E)-FPP, (Z,E)-FPP, (Z,Z)-FPP & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}γ-curcumen, α-zingiberene, \\ β-bisabolene, β-curcumene, \\ sesquiphellandrene, (E)-α-bisabolene, \\ (Z)-α-bisabolene, γ-curcumene, \\ zingiberene, β-sesquiphellandrene\end{tabular} &  \\ \cline{1-4}
%\textit{Anomodon rostratus} & Mos-VBMM-MTPSL3 & (E,E)-FPP, (Z,E)-FPP, (Z,Z)-FPP, (E,E,E)-GGPP & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}(E)-β-farnesene, γ-curcumene, \\ α-zingiberen, β-bisabolene, \\ β-curcumene, (E)-α-bisabolene,  \\ (Z)-γ- bisabolene, (E)-γ-bisabolene, \\ β-bisabolol, α-bisabolol, β-bisabolene, \\ (Z)-γ-bisabolene, (Z)-α-bisabolene, \\ γ-curcumene, (E)-γ- bisabolene,\\ multiple unidentified diterpenes\end{tabular} &  \\ \cline{1-4}
%\textit{Anthoceros punctatus} & Hon-ApMTPSL7 & GPP, (E,E)-FPP, (Z,E)-FPP, (Z,Z)-FPP &  &  \\ \cline{1-4}
%\textit{Myriopteris eatonii} & Mon-GSXD-MTPSL3 & (E,E)-FPP, (Z,E)-FPP & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}(Z,E)-α-farnesene, (E,E)-α-farnesene, \\ (E)-β-farnesene, (E,E)-α-farnesene\end{tabular} &  \\ \cline{1-4}
%\textit{Pityrogramma trifoliata} & Mon-UJTT-MTPSL4 & GPP, (E,E)-FPP, (Z,E)-FPP, (Z,Z)-FPP & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Myrcene, (Z)-β-ocimene, \\ (E)-β-ocimene, linalool, \\ protoillud-6-ene, \\ multiple unidentified ST, \\ epi-bicyclosesquiphellandrene, \\ γ-cadinene, δ-cadinene, α-cadinene, \\ γ-curcumene\end{tabular} &  \\ \cline{1-4}
%\textit{Woodsia scopulina} & Mon-YJJY-MTPSL1 & (E,E)-FPP, (Z,E)-FPP, (Z,Z)-FPP & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Protoillud-6-ene, \\ multiple unidentified ST, \\ epi-bicyclosesquiphellandrene, \\ γ-cadinene, δ-cadinene, α-cadinene, \\ γ-curcumene\end{tabular} & \multirow{-9}{*}{Jia et. al (2016)} \\ \hline
%\textit{Porphyridium purpureum} & PpMTPSL & (E,E)-FPP, (E,E,E)-GGPP & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}β-Elemene, aristol-9-ene, β-copaene, \\ germacrene A, \\ multiple unidentified ST, \\ unidentified oxygenated sesquiterpene\end{tabular} &  \\ \cline{1-4}
% & EaMTPSL1 & GPP, (E,E)-FPP & Linalol, nerolidol &  \\ \cline{2-4}
%\multirow{-2}{*}{\textit{Erythrolobus australicus}} & EaMTPSL2 & (E,E)-FPP & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}β-Elemene, aristol-9-ene, β-copaene, \\ unidentified oxygenated sesquiterpene, \\ α-ylangene, α-muurolene, \\ multiple unidentified ST, \\ (Z)-α-bisabolene epoxide\end{tabular} & \multirow{-3}{*}{Wei 2019} \\ \hline
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```