# Repeat cell data on each page of multi page longtable

Tags: longtable, multicolumn, multirow

I have a long table and I am using the code

```
\begin{longtable}[c]{|p{5cm} | c | p{5cm}|}
    \caption{My table.\label{tab:long}}\\
     \hline
        AA & B & C \\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Continuation of Table \ref{tab:Long}}\\
     \hline
        AA & B & C \\
    \hline
    \endhead
    \hline
    \endfoot

    \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{| c |}{End of Table}\\
    \hline\hline
    \endlastfoot
    a &\multirow{20}{1em}{b}  & c \\
    a &  & c \\
    a &  & c \\
    a &  & c \\
    a &  & c \\
    a &  & c \\
    a &  & c \\
    a &  & c \\
    a &  & c \\
    a &  & c \\
    a &  & c \\
    a &  & c \\
    a &  & c \\
    a &  & c \\
    a &  & c \\
    a &  & c \\
    a &  & c \\
    a &  & c \\
    a &  & c \\
    a &  & c \\ \hline

    
    a & \multirow{20}{1em}{x} & c \\
    a &  & c \\
    a &  & c \\
    a &  & c \\
    a &  & c \\
    a &  & c \\
    a &  & c \\
    a &  & c \\
    a &  & c \\
    a &  & c \\
    a &  & c \\
    a &  & c \\
    a &  & c \\
    a &  & c \\
    a &  & c \\ 
    \end{longtable}
```

I want the data of multirow cell to repeat on newpage.

Comment: Why you should repeat cell data on each page? Isn't it better this data to include to captions of table, which can be easy repeated to each page?

Comment: i have more than one mulitirow columns and table is 3 to 4 pages long

Comment: Which "multicolumn cell"  are you referring to?

Comment: As I suggest you, the number of pages can be any. You just omit this column and this information move to the captions, which repeat on each page.

Comment: do you mean you want the muli**row** to repeat on each page? the only multi**column** I see is in the table head and does repeat. I do not understand the question at all.

Comment: Yes david, you got it right, I want multirow to repeat on each page. I have edited the question.

Comment: Combining `longtable` with `\multirow` is usually a bit "risky"  especially when it comes to multirows spanning a large number of rows since depending on the position of the page breaks, the contents of the multirow might end up overlapping the footer of the page. I thus recommend using a different approach  to present the information without the need for a multirow. (For examples of such a redesign see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/568292/134144 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/537076/134144)